# What is the best way for implementing multilanguage support in J2ME applications?

Tags: internationalization, multilingual, j2mepolish

What is the best way for implementing multilanguage support in J2ME applications? I want my application in different languages, but up to know have not found any appropriate way to do that. Could you please help me in this issue?

Answer (score 0):

hey you can check out j2me polish it supports localization and it is very easy to use